# Neo4j embedded with OSGi

Tags: osgi, neo4j

I want to use neo4j in embedded mode. As I have seen it's not possible to share the `GraphDatabase` instance in different processes. Now my idea was to use the neo4j embedded in an OSGi container to share the same db for different components. Is it a good idea to write a `BundleActivator` which creates the `GraphDB` and exposes it to other OSGi bundles with a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is [An example template setup with tests](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-osgi) making a super-bundle out of the neo4j-related components. Try and let us know how it goes. See [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-osgi/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/org/neo4j/examples/osgi/Neo4jActivator.java) for a typical Activator.

Comment: Trying to build the example fails with: Failed to execute goal com.mycila.maven-license-plugin:maven-license-plugin:1.9.0:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-osgi-examples: Some files do not have the expected license header

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use proper DI to instantiate the DB, like http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded-osgi.html

```
    //the cache providers
    ArrayList<CacheProvider> cacheList = new ArrayList<CacheProvider>();
    cacheList.add( new SoftCacheProvider() );

    //the index providers
    IndexProvider lucene = new LuceneIndexProvider();
    ArrayList<IndexProvider> provs = new ArrayList<IndexProvider>();
    provs.add( lucene );
    ListIndexIterable providers = new ListIndexIterable();
    providers.setIndexProviders( provs );

    //the database setup
    GraphDatabaseFactory gdbf = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    gdbf.setIndexProviders( providers );
    gdbf.setCacheProviders( cacheList );
    db = gdbf.newEmbeddedDatabase( "target/db" );
```